# Scrollbars always visible in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I want some scrollbars to always be visible.
I'm using the following css for this.

```
.frameXY {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}

.frameXY::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.frameXY::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

.frameXY::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

.frameXY::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.frameX {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.frameX::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.frameX::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

.frameX::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

.frameX::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

This is working in Chrome (scrollbars always visible) but not in Firefox (scrollbars appear initially and then disappear).
How can I achieve the same effect in Firefox?

Comment: You can't change the Firefox scrollbar with Webkit CSS (it's Chrome only). Also, I don't think you can change the Firefox scrollbar anymore.

Answer (score -4):

Setting `overflow: scroll;` would do the fix. This will show scrollbars even if they are not needed. `overflow: auto;` will tell the browser to decide to show or hide scrollbars

Comment: I am setting the overflow (x and y) as scroll in my css already. It is not showing the scrollbars in firefox, but it shows it in Chrome